# Does Perl execute code that appears after the return; function?

Tags: perl, scripting, subroutine

I have an ugly Perl subroutine that has a nested if statement that returns different values depending on the conditions.  It's ugly because I don't like nested if statements.  They're hard to follow so I want to break it up into separate if statements but I'm not sure if it'll change the way the subroutine performs.  The original subroutine follows:

```
 sub TacacsInstalled(){

    my $Installed;
    my $InstalledVersion;
    my $InstalledRelease;
    my $NewVersion;
    my $NewRelease;

    $Installed = `rpm -qa | grep tac_plus | wc -l`;
    chomp $Installed;

    # Check to see if Tacacs is installed.
    if ($Installed == 0){ # Tacacs is not installed. Fresh install.
        return "False";
    } else { # Tacacs is installed.  Is it an old version?
        $InstalledVersion = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
        chomp $InstalledVersion;
        $NewVersion = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
        chomp $NewVersion;

        if ($InstalledVersion < $NewVersion) { # Current installed version is too old, must update.
            return "False";
        } else { # Maybe the release is newer.
            $InstalledRelease = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
            chomp $InstalledRelease;
            $NewRelease = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
            chomp $NewRelease;

            if ($InstalledRelease < $NewRelease) { # Current installed release is too old, must update.
                return "False";

            } else { # Installed release is newer than or equal to what we're trying to install. Do nothing.
                return "True";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could I improve this code by using the following instead?

```
sub TacacsInstalled(){

    my $Installed;
    my $InstalledVersion;
    my $InstalledRelease;
    my $NewVersion;
    my $NewRelease;

    $Installed = `rpm -qa | grep tac_plus | wc -l`;
    chomp $Installed;

    # Check to see if Tacacs is installed.
    if ($Installed == 0){ return "False" }; # Tacacs is not installed perform a fresh install.

    # If we got this far then Tacacs must be installed.  Is it an old version?
    $InstalledVersion = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
    chomp $InstalledVersion;
    $NewVersion = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
    chomp $NewVersion;      

    if ($InstalledVersion < $NewVersion) { return "False" }; # Current installed version is too old, must update.

    # The Version is the same so then is the release is newer?
    $InstalledRelease = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
    chomp $InstalledRelease;
    $NewRelease = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
    chomp $NewRelease;

    if ($InstalledRelease < $NewRelease) { return "False" }; # Current installed release is too old, must update.

    # Installed release is newer than or equal to what we're trying to install. Do nothing.
    return "True";

}
```

Comment: One way to tackle question like this, that is surely longer to do but with many more benefits: write unit tests that exercise your code, and do coverage to make sure that indeed all your branches are explored by some tests. Then change your code in any way you see fit. Then rerun the unit tests. You will then have the confidence of not having broken something. Of course in this specific case it is easier said than done since you will first need to abstract all your `rpm` calls, otherwise unit testing that will be hard...

Comment: Also, meta: I do not know about `rpm` but I know, if IIRC, that with `dpkg` you have specific commands to do exactly what you are trying to do in Perl, that is test if something is installed, with some specific version/release, etc. It may be worthwhile to explore that in the long term, if `rpm` provides the same kind of features, which should be "natural". Because code like that using external tool not designed for such use is inherently brittle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Perl does not execute code after a `return`.  That's the whole point of `return`!

Comment: Marking this one as the answer since it does indeed answer the topic question as shown in the title.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use prototypes on Perl subroutines. Just `sub TacacsInstalled { ... }` is correct
- Use `snake_case` in preference to `CamelCase` identifiers
- Declare all your variables as *late as possible*, never in a block at the top of your code
- Make proper use of Perl's statement modifiers
- None of your backtick strings look correct: you have a spare double quote at the end of each of them. And double quotes don't need escaping within backtick strings

I would also say that returning Perl *true* or *false* values (`0`, `'0'`, and `undef` are false; anything else is true) is superior to returning `True` and `False` strings

I would write this

```
sub tacacs_installed {

    my $installed = `rpm -qa | grep tac_plus | wc -l`;
    chomp $installed;

    return 'False' if $installed == 0;    # Tacacs is not installed. Fresh install.

    my $installed_version = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
    chomp $installed_version;

    my $new_version = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\""`;
    chomp $new_version;

    return 'False' if $installed_version < $new_version;  # Current installed version is too old, must update.

    my $installed_release = `rpm -q tac_plus --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
    chomp $installed_release;

    my $new_release = `rpm -qp ./tac_plus*.x86_64.rpm --queryformat \"%{RELEASE}\""`;
    chomp $new_release;

    return 'False' if $installed_release < $new_release;  # Current installed release is too old, must update.

    return 'True';
}
```

Comment: Do not return false. Just use an empty return: `return;` This will return `undef` (false) in scalar context and an empty list `()` in list context. An empty return is the same as: `return wantarray ? () : undef;`

Comment: @shawn: It's the same as `return ()`! Evaluating an empty list in scalar context gives `undef`.

Comment: @Borodin: Thank you for providing the very constructive criticism.  There is a lot I can learn from this and I will incorporate your code.  I did notice shortly afterward that my backtick strings had an extra " character.

Comment: @Borodin Yes it does but evaluating an empty array in scalar context gives 0. One of the difference between lists and arrays.  For return, it's best to let Perl decide.

Comment: @shawnhcorey no.  that is commonly given advice, but it is very wrong.  a sub that is designed to return just a scalar should always do so, whether called in scalar or list context.  only subs that return lists should use bare `return;`

Comment: @shawn: No one mentioned arrays and I can't see how they're related to this. Or are you thinking that `wantarray` actually relates to arrays? It really should be `wantlist`, as it says whether the call was made in *list context*.

Comment: @Borodin You mentioned arrays. `()` is an empty array. `return();` converts the empty array into a list to return it. The difference between arrays and lists is a difficult thing to learn in Perl.

Comment: @shawn: `()` is *absolutely not* an empty array, although `[]` *does* create an array and returns a reference to it. If `()` were an array then why can't I assign a list to it,  why is its value in scalar context not its size, why can I not take a reference to it, and why can I not `push`, `pop` and `splice` it? *"The difference between arrays and lists is a difficult thing to learn in Perl"* It definitely seems so, even for "Perl Gurus"!